# RMS error, AME, correlation from text files and exporting summery statistics in excel in matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, machine-learning, correlation, missing-data

**Dear Experts;**

I am trying to make a code which able to calculate **RMS, AME, correlation** of 24 text files with name **output_00.txt to ouput_23.txt** in a folder. After reading each file, i make **30%** of my sample(total sample are 323) in each text file as **-9999.0** then using **scatter data interpolation**, i interpolate these -9999.0 value and commute RMS error, AME, correlation.

**UPDATE 2**

```
    S = dir('interpot_linear_*.txt');
N = sort({S.name});

for K = 1 : length(N)
  infile = N{K};
  whichfile = sscanf(infile, 'interpot_linear_%c%c');
% Load the data
data = load(infile);
  % separate the data columns, just to make the code clear
    Lat = data(:,1); % Column 1 is Latitude
    Lon = data(:,2); % Column 2 is Longitude
    Tmp = data(:,3); % Column 3 is Temperature
     % Creating 30% of sample as -9999.0
     n=size(data,1);
     %n=323;
    nr=round(n*0.3);
    idx30=randperm(n,nr);
    Tmp(idx30)=-9999.0;
     % Find the "good" data points
    good_temp = find(Tmp > -9999.000);
     % find the "bad" data points
    bad_temp = find(Tmp == -9999.000);
      % creating vector 
      T = scatteredInterpolant(Lat(good_temp), Lon(good_temp), Tmp(good_temp), 'linear');
    % use the interpolation object to interpolate temperature values
      interp_values = T(Lat(bad_temp), Lon(bad_temp));
      % replace the bad values with the interpolated values
      Tmp(bad_temp) = interp_values;
      %recall oringinal temperature column
    Tmp_original=data(:,3);
    % Here calculate RMS error
   RMS=sqrt(sum((Tmp_original(:)-Tmp(:)).^2)/n);
    % Here calculate mean absolute error
    MAE=sum(abs(Tmp_original(:)-Tmp(:)))/n;
    % Here calculate correlation coefficient
    correl=corr(Tmp_original(:),Tmp(:));
    %here i am spliting R^2 as two different terms
    M_org= mean(Tmp_original); % mean of original temperature data.
    M_ext= mean(Tmp); % mean of extimated temperature data.
    std_org=std(Tmp_original); % standard deviation of orginal temp
    std_ext=std(Tmp); % standard deviation of extimated temp.
    total=length(Tmp_original);
    M1=(Tmp_original(:)- M_org);
    M2=(Tmp(:)- M_ext);
    M1=M1';
    % Here i am creating numminator of the formula
    Nu=M1*M2;  %giveing sum (M1*M2) 
    % Here i am creating dinominator of the formula
    div=total*std_org*std_ext;
    %R ^2
    R=(Nu/div)^2;
    rep(K,1)=RMS; rep(K,2)=MAE; rep(K,3)=correl; rep(K,4)=R; rep(K,5)=str2num(whichfile);
end
  xlswrite('statistics',rep);
```

I want to **export summary statistics** of these 24 txt file in **excel/text** file which contains **four columns** i.e. first column is file no, second no RMS error, third column AME and fourth column correlation value for this file?

My **one text file looks like this**

```
21.500  60.500  295.867 
21.500  61.500  295.828 
21.500  62.500  295.828 
21.500  63.500  295.867 
21.500  64.500  296.102 
21.500  65.500  296.234 
21.500  66.500  296.352 
21.500  67.500  296.336 
21.500  68.500  296.305 
21.500  69.500  298.281 
21.500  70.500  301.828 
21.500  71.500  302.094 
21.500  72.500  299.469 
21.500  73.500  301.711 
21.500  74.500  302.317 
21.500  75.500  302.757 
21.500  76.500  303.030 
21.500  77.500  303.137 
21.500  78.500  303.078 
22.500  60.500  295.477 
22.500  61.500  295.484 
22.500  62.500  295.516 
22.500  63.500  295.547 
22.500  64.500  295.852 
22.500  65.500  295.859 
22.500  66.500  295.852 
22.500  67.500  295.711 
22.500  68.500  295.969 
22.500  69.500  298.562 
22.500  70.500  300.828 
22.500  71.500  302.352 
22.500  72.500  300.570 
22.500  73.500  301.383 
22.500  74.500  301.311 
22.500  75.500  301.381 
22.500  76.500  301.692 
22.500  77.500  301.837 
22.500  78.500  301.814 
23.500  60.500  294.906 
23.500  61.500  294.898 
23.500  62.500  295.000 
23.500  63.500  295.078 
23.500  64.500  295.297 
23.500  65.500  295.359 
23.500  66.500  295.297 
23.500  67.500  295.312 
23.500  68.500  296.664 
23.500  69.500  298.781 
23.500  70.500  299.211 
23.500  71.500  300.109 
23.500  72.500  301.000 
23.500  73.500  301.594 
23.500  74.500  302.000 
23.500  75.500  300.911 
23.500  76.500  300.520 
23.500  77.500  300.702 
23.500  78.500  300.718 
24.500  60.500  294.578 
24.500  61.500  294.516 
24.500  62.500  294.734 
24.500  63.500  294.789 
24.500  64.500  294.844 
24.500  65.500  294.562 
24.500  66.500  294.734 
24.500  67.500  296.367 
24.500  68.500  297.438 
24.500  69.500  298.531 
24.500  70.500  298.453 
24.500  71.500  299.195 
24.500  72.500  300.062 
24.500  73.500  300.351 
24.500  74.500  301.055 
24.500  75.500  300.958 
24.500  76.500  300.512 
24.500  77.500  299.734 
24.500  78.500  299.787 
25.500  60.500  296.258 
25.500  61.500  296.391 
25.500  62.500  296.672 
25.500  63.500  296.398 
25.500  64.500  295.773 
25.500  65.500  295.812 
25.500  66.500  296.609 
25.500  67.500  297.977 
25.500  68.500  297.109 
25.500  69.500  297.828 
25.500  70.500  298.430 
25.500  71.500  298.836 
25.500  72.500  298.703 
25.500  73.500  300.207 
25.500  74.500  300.110 
25.500  75.500  300.013 
25.500  76.500  299.917 
25.500  77.500  299.470 
25.500  78.500  299.023 
26.500  60.500  294.484 
26.500  61.500  298.266 
26.500  62.500  296.773 
26.500  63.500  296.892 
26.500  64.500  297.012 
26.500  65.500  297.131 
26.500  66.500  297.250 
26.500  67.500  296.188 
26.500  68.500  295.938 
26.500  69.500  296.906 
26.500  70.500  297.828 
26.500  71.500  299.312 
26.500  72.500  299.359 
26.500  73.500  299.262 
26.500  74.500  299.165 
26.500  75.500  299.069 
26.500  76.500  298.972 
26.500  77.500  298.875 
26.500  78.500  296.773 
27.500  60.500  292.710 
27.500  61.500  295.880 
27.500  62.500  294.643 
27.500  63.500  295.710 
27.500  64.500  296.362 
27.500  65.500  296.333 
27.500  66.500  296.452 
27.500  67.500  295.352 
27.500  68.500  295.148 
27.500  69.500  295.750 
27.500  70.500  295.750 
27.500  71.500  296.070 
27.500  72.500  295.227 
27.500  73.500  297.534 
27.500  74.500  297.437 
27.500  75.500  297.340 
27.500  76.500  297.870 
27.500  77.500  297.405 
27.500  78.500  296.609 
28.500  60.500  290.935 
28.500  61.500  293.494 
28.500  62.500  292.513 
28.500  63.500  293.580 
28.500  64.500  294.647 
28.500  65.500  295.715 
28.500  66.500  295.951 
28.500  67.500  295.773 
28.500  68.500  295.375 
28.500  69.500  295.438 
28.500  70.500  294.664 
28.500  71.500  294.906 
28.500  72.500  294.812 
28.500  73.500  295.805 
28.500  74.500  296.335 
28.500  75.500  296.864 
28.500  76.500  296.731 
28.500  77.500  294.557 
28.500  78.500  294.696 
29.500  60.500  289.161 
29.500  61.500  291.108 
29.500  62.500  290.383 
29.500  63.500  291.450 
29.500  64.500  292.517 
29.500  65.500  293.585 
29.500  66.500  294.652 
29.500  67.500  295.719 
29.500  68.500  296.797 
29.500  69.500  293.375 
29.500  70.500  294.305 
29.500  71.500  294.070 
29.500  72.500  293.750 
29.500  73.500  295.539 
29.500  74.500  295.859 
29.500  75.500  296.057 
29.500  76.500  292.532 
29.500  77.500  292.799 
29.500  78.500  292.924 
30.500  60.500  287.387 
30.500  61.500  288.722 
30.500  62.500  288.253 
30.500  63.500  289.320 
30.500  64.500  290.387 
30.500  65.500  291.455 
30.500  66.500  292.522 
30.500  67.500  292.884 
30.500  68.500  294.198 
30.500  69.500  295.394 
30.500  70.500  293.320 
30.500  71.500  292.930 
30.500  72.500  293.570 
30.500  73.500  294.648 
30.500  74.500  295.383 
30.500  75.500  290.535 
30.500  76.500  290.929 
30.500  77.500  291.182 
30.500  78.500  291.294 
31.500  60.500  285.613 
31.500  61.500  286.336 
31.500  62.500  286.123 
31.500  63.500  287.190 
31.500  64.500  288.257 
31.500  65.500  289.325 
31.500  66.500  289.239 
31.500  67.500  290.049 
31.500  68.500  291.364 
31.500  69.500  292.678 
31.500  70.500  293.992 
31.500  71.500  293.422 
31.500  72.500  294.438 
31.500  73.500  294.141 
31.500  74.500  288.564 
31.500  75.500  289.087 
31.500  76.500  289.468 
31.500  77.500  289.707 
31.500  78.500  289.805 
32.500  60.500  283.839 
32.500  61.500  283.950 
32.500  62.500  283.993 
32.500  63.500  285.060 
32.500  64.500  286.127 
32.500  65.500  286.272 
32.500  66.500  285.726 
32.500  67.500  287.214 
32.500  68.500  288.529 
32.500  69.500  289.843 
32.500  70.500  291.847 
32.500  71.500  294.312 
32.500  72.500  294.812 
32.500  73.500  286.621 
32.500  74.500  287.271 
32.500  75.500  287.781 
32.500  76.500  288.148 
32.500  77.500  288.374 
32.500  78.500  288.458 
33.500  60.500  282.065 
33.500  61.500  281.564 
33.500  62.500  281.863 
33.500  63.500  282.930 
33.500  64.500  283.306 
33.500  65.500  282.759 
33.500  66.500  282.405 
33.500  67.500  284.380 
33.500  68.500  285.694 
33.500  69.500  287.238 
33.500  70.500  289.703 
33.500  71.500  291.025 
33.500  72.500  284.704 
33.500  73.500  285.483 
33.500  74.500  286.120 
33.500  75.500  286.616 
33.500  76.500  286.970 
33.500  77.500  287.182 
33.500  78.500  287.253 
34.500  60.500  280.290 
34.500  61.500  279.178 
34.500  62.500  279.733 
34.500  63.500  280.339 
34.500  64.500  279.792 
34.500  65.500  279.246 
34.500  66.500  279.278 
34.500  67.500  281.545 
34.500  68.500  282.859 
34.500  69.500  285.093 
34.500  70.500  287.237 
34.500  71.500  282.814 
34.500  72.500  283.722 
34.500  73.500  284.487 
34.500  74.500  285.111 
34.500  75.500  285.593 
34.500  76.500  285.933 
34.500  77.500  286.132 
34.500  78.500  286.189 
35.500  60.500  278.516 
35.500  61.500  276.792 
35.500  62.500  277.373 
35.500  63.500  276.826 
35.500  64.500  276.279 
35.500  65.500  275.732 
35.500  66.500  276.150 
35.500  67.500  278.710 
35.500  68.500  280.484 
35.500  69.500  283.450 
35.500  70.500  280.952 
35.500  71.500  281.987 
35.500  72.500  282.881 
35.500  73.500  283.633 
35.500  74.500  284.243 
35.500  75.500  284.712 
35.500  76.500  285.039 
35.500  77.500  285.224 
35.500  78.500  285.267 
36.500  60.500  276.742 
36.500  61.500  274.406 
36.500  62.500  273.859 
36.500  63.500  273.313 
36.500  64.500  272.766 
36.500  65.500  272.219 
36.500  66.500  273.023 
36.500  67.500  275.875 
36.500  68.500  279.662 
36.500  69.500  279.117 
36.500  70.500  280.280 
36.500  71.500  281.302 
36.500  72.500  282.182 
36.500  73.500  282.920 
36.500  74.500  283.517 
36.500  75.500  283.972 
36.500  76.500  284.285 
36.500  77.500  284.457 
36.500  78.500  284.487 
37.500  60.500  277.406 
37.500  61.500  277.547 
37.500  62.500  276.375 
37.500  63.500  275.484 
37.500  64.500  276.820 
37.500  65.500  275.312 
37.500  66.500  274.875 
37.500  67.500  275.875 
37.500  68.500  277.308 
37.500  69.500  278.600 
37.500  70.500  279.750 
37.500  71.500  280.758 
37.500  72.500  281.624 
37.500  73.500  282.349 
37.500  74.500  282.932 
37.500  75.500  283.374 
37.500  76.500  283.674 
37.500  77.500  283.832 
37.500  78.500  283.849
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

1. if your filenames are `output_00.txt` (e.g. they start with a lowercase "o") than you must change your first line of code to `S = dir('output_*.txt');`. Matlab is case-sensitive. If your file names start with a lowercase "o" then Matlab will never find files whose name start with "Output" (capital "O"). This will maybe solve the error in `data`. The same file name problem will affect the `sscanf()`, so also in `sscanf()` you must have the lowercase "o".
2. the RMSE formula is incorrect: you do not square both items and then subtract them, you must do the other way round; that is, subtraction first and then raise to the power. The correct formula is `RMS=sqrt(sum((Tmp_original(:)-Tmp(:)).^2)/n);`
3. the variables `RMS`, `correl` and `MAE` are scalars, so it is pointless to do the `(:)` operator, which is used to unwrap variables as column vectors
4. `rep` is declared as a 24x3 matrix but then with the line `rep=[RMS(:);MAE(:);correl(:)];` you make `rep` a 3x1 vector.
5. in the final for loop there are a couple of issues: the first argument in `xlmwrite()` (e.g. `Statistics`) must be a string, not a variable (unless such variable contains the file name as a string). And the second argument must be replaced with `rep`.
6. `Tmp` and `Tmp_original` are both column vectors, so it is pointless to do the `(:)` operator. See above.

Since your main concern is regarding the saving-to-disk problem, I'll concentrate on that. My suggestion is to build `rep` as a matrix and then save such matrix outside the for-loop, once all of your files have been scanned and processed. As your code is now, it is not clear whether you want `rep` to be a matrix and save to disk all at once or you want `rep` to be a vector and save to disk in a file-by-file fashion.

1. the first thing to do then is to move `rep=zeros(24,3);` all the way up, before the for-loop starts. If you also want to append the file ID, then `rep` should actually be a 24x4 matrix.
2. change `rep=[RMS(:);MAE(:);correl(:)];` to `rep(k,1)=RMS; rep(k,2)=MAE; rep(k,3)=correl;`. In this manner you write `RMS` on the k-th row and 1st column , then you write `MAE` on the k-th row and 2nd column and same story goes for `correl`. As `k` goes, this will fill the matrix `rep`. If you also want to append the file ID, keep in mind that `whichfile` is a string and you cannot concatenate strings and numbers into the same matrix. The immediate option is to convert `whichfile` from string to numeric thanks to `str2num()` but keep in mind that such conversion will remove the leading zeros (Matlab does not allow leading zeros) so the file ID `00` will be `0`, the file `01` will be `1` and so on. So you might want to add `rep(k,4)=str2num(whichfile);` and this will also fill the 4th column in `rep`.
3. remove the inner for-loop, the one that contains `xlmwrite()`. Instead of writing a single line for every single file, we'll write the whole `rep` matrix in a batch mode.
4. after the main for-loop, put `xlmwrite()` as follows: `xlmwrite('myFinalFile',rep);` and if everything went ok, `myFinalFile` should contain your `rep` matrix as a 24x3 matrix. You might as well change `myFinalFile` with the file name you prefer.

Comment: In options of problems in my code.  (1) my files are start with uppercase O (2) i have correct RMS formula (3)(4) (5) i got these points and corrected. (6) i do not get it. Tell me `Tmp_original (:) `  will produce error in  my calculation or run finely?  In problems of modification in my code (1) i delete this line `rep=zeros(24,3);` from the code (2) update this line to code (3)  I have remove for loop of ` xlmwrite() ` but unable to understand meaning of ** write the whole rep matrix in a batch mode?.**

Comment: dear @MuhammadUsmanSaleem, if your file names start with capital O, both the `sscanf()` and the `dir()` commands are fine. Regarding (6), `Tmp` and `Tmp_original` since they both already are column vector it is pointless to do `Tmp(:)` and `Tmp_original(:)` because the `(:)` operator will unwrap a given variable to a column vector, but (again) since they both are column vectors is rather pointless. It is not an error, it's just an improvement ;)

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSaleem you want an excel file or a .txt file? With `xlswrite()` you create Microsoft Excel files and won't work for .txt files.

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSaleem, don't use a .txt file then. If you want an excel file just choose a .csv (`csvwrite()` function) or .xls (`xlswrite()`)

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSaleem, "batch mode" is like saying we're doing it all at once and not one by one. In our case we create the `rep` matrix in its entirely and then we write it on disk. Thanks to step #3 we create the whole `rep` matrix. After the for-loop (i.e. after all files have been scanned and therefore `rep` is complete) we write the matrix `rep` to file thanks to `xlmwrite()`, if you want that in .xls format, or `csvwrite()`, if you want that is .csv format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107890/discussion-between-muhammad-usman-saleem-and-alessiox).

Answer (score 3):

So your problem is that in one of iterations the file that is loaded and assigned to data (in line 8 of your code) is empty,hence the size of data is [0,0].

I assume there is a file that is empty that's why you get this response.

So try to find that file,best way is run the script and see in which value of K you get the error and then navigate to the text file see whether it really is empty.

Comment: @Adili Adil not a big programmer i am. Please check this error and how can i export summery statistics of each file in excel or text file? Even i am not sure what i have written at the end of the code?

Comment: exporting to a file you can do it with dlmwrite function as follows;
filename = 'myFile.txt'
dlmwrite(filename,data_to_be_written);
Check this link on further documentation:
http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html

Btw did that error dissapear?

Comment: I have delete it. Now when i try make a matrix of each results through       results=[RMS';MAE';correl']';  and even  rep=[RMS(:);MAE(:);correl(:)];  It is storing statistics of only 24 no text file(last one). How can i store summery statistics of each file and end  24 * 3 matrix and then how can i export to results in excel? Please

Comment: dlmwrite('myFile.csv',rep) should do the job.
And please if my answer is correct can you please accept it as a correct asnwer.

Comment: no, i just move one step ahead. I want to makes 23*4 matrix of statistics of each text file and have to export it to excel. Please update your answer again.